# How to change the default opening of folders by vscode on Arch?

Tags: directory, archlinux, xdgutils

Whether on the desktop, the application dock, or even with search, gnome opens folders directly to vs-code. I would like it to open them for me with the default gnome file application.
And strangely I don't have the problem when I try to open a folder from File Explorer.

Thank you for your help.

I did some manipulations a while ago but I don't remember which ones.
I would like to be able to open my folders with File Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the appropriate line in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, switching the order of `code` and `nautilus`.

From:

```
inode/directory=code.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
```

To:

```
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;code.desktop;
```

Answer (score 0):

The manual change in the `mimeinfo.cache` file from @Raph0603 were overwritten when i restarted my computer. If you want to make the change permanently you can use the following command:

```
gio mime inode/directory org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=289369)